# swift app doesn't show navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, ios-simulator

I'm working on my first iOS based application where I'm having problem with embedded navigation controller. I've a home screen or a view with "Home" as a title and embedded navigation controller. While testing on simulator, I've seen that occasionally when application starts it doesn't show the "Home" navigation bar. If I close the application and try again then the navigation bar shows up. I'm not able to root cause the issue. Recently I also added following code to my "HomeController",

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
 }
```

But I still see the same issue. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Atarang, could you clarify one point? Did you embedded the navigation controller inside your view controller? Because the usual way is to embed your view controller inside a navigation controller; the opposite that you just did

Comment: Initially I'd home controller marked as an initial controller.  Then I added few buttons to the home view, and created segue to other controllers. In order to add navigation, I selected 'HomeController' and embedded "navigation controller" from editor-menu. This added new controller before "home controller" and marked as a 'initial controller'. After running the app, I could see the navigation bar which I used to label 'home view' as "Home". Did I do anything wrong? Yes, I did use storyboard.

Comment: Are you using storyboard?

Comment: Could you please share which kind of segue did you choose? And how did you call them?

Comment: I started with a homeview (a view controller) and a login view. Idea was when a user tries to access homeview but not authenticated then it redirects or opens up login view. To support this, I embedded navigation controller into homeviewcontroller.

Comment: I found the issue. I was erroneously resetting root view controller to login view in Appdelegate.swift for the initial condition (if user is not logged in). I moved that login into my first controller 'homeviewcontroller' which fixed the problem. Thanks for belagoesr for asking question about 'segue kind' which prompted me to look at the segue and corresponding logic. So thanks belagoesr.